# c# MySQL Connect I gоt a System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, connection

I try to display some  with places from database on the SearchBar with xamarin.

I use this method with button and I not have any problems.. everything is ok..

```
void Btn_GetPlaces(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            LabelSQL.Text = "Global connection to database is open.";

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"CALL nearest3({GlobalLat}, {GlobalLong}, 1)", connection);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // access your record colums by using reader
                    LabelPlace.Text = (reader[0]).ToString();
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelSQL.Text = (ex.ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

When I want to use another select query to put my staff on the  for SearchBar I have a connection problem on this part of code:

```
IEnumerable<Contacts> GetContacts(string searchText = null)
    {
        connection.Open();
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        var contacts = new List<Contacts>();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT place,x,y FROM places ORDER BY place", connection);
        
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var place = new Contacts
                {
                    Place = reader[0].ToString()
                };
                contacts.Add(place);  
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            return contacts;
        return contacts.Where(p => p.Place.StartsWith(searchText));
    }
```

Here in the constructor I set the connection string with this code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = GetContacts();
        this.BindingContext = this;

        server = "192.168.0.1,3306";
        database = "NameDB";
        uid = "userr";
        password = "pass@";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this problem ? Can I get some example, because Im new to this world. Thank you.

Comment: What problem do you need to fix?  Your question does not contain any description of an actual problem.  Your title mentions a NullRef exception, but there is not detailed description of this in your post.  Which **specific** line causes the exception, and what is the stack trace?

Comment: I say: When I want to use another select querry to put my staff on the for SearchBar I have a connection problem on this part of code: <CODE> What you not understand ?

Comment: Again, which **specific** line causes the exception?

Comment: The error is on: connection.Open();

Comment: When it stands to reason that your `connection` object is null.  Test for this and create a new one if necessary.